# UTMStack: AD Audit Integration

Tags: utm

I am trying to enable the AD Audit integration but I'm getting an error "Windows events are not being logged"

I have the agent installed on the Domain Controller that i am pointing it to and i can see the winlogbeats logs coming in ok.

Answer (score 0):

Directory Service Change auditing needs to be enabled.

Use the following commands:

Get current audit settings:
`auditpol /get /category:*`

Confirm that Advanced Auditing is enabled:
`reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA /v SCENoApplyLegacyAuditPolicy`

Enable Directory Service Change auditing:

**Audit Directory Service Changes**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-directory-service-changes

**AD Audit Configuration**
https://docs.utmstack.com/books/ad-auditor/page/ad-audit

Note that auditing also needs to be enabled on the AD objects themselves. This typically means adding a System Access Control List (SACL) at the root of the object hierarchies, specifying that modifications and deletes are audited.  These should be added to the root of the domain in AD Users and Computers (dsa.msc), and the root of the Sites config container in AD Sites and Services (dssite.msc).

If all is configured correctly, there should be plenty of change events (Event Id 5136) in the security event log, due to objects are frequently changed during normal operation. You can also test creation/deletion of objects to create 5137 and 5141 events, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, i currently have auditing enabled as i have another product that pulls these logs ok.

i noticed on a screenshot in the documentation, for a log source under the data type it has wineventlog. When i install the agent on my device i only get hids as a data type. Could this be the issue? 
I can see the logon and logoff events in the log viewer

Comment: Seems like it may be related. Intrusion detection wouldn't necessarily be related to this capability.

Comment: Yeah it seems although all the Windows Event logs are being pulled through, none of the Windows Activity Dashboards or the AD audit section are displaying any data. Is there a way to force wineventlog as a type for a data source?